# Can I change the default Google Docs suggestion mode text format so suggestion text is highlighted yellow?

Tags: google-docs

I am using suggestions mode to make changes to a large google doc. When I have finished making my suggestions, I will need to print off the document for a group review meeting to go through the suggestions, get approvals, feedback, etc. However, we only have black and white printers which I think will make it difficult to see which text are suggestions in the print-outs.

Is there a way to change the format of suggestion text so it will stand out when printed in black and white? I was thinking that ideally I would make suggestion text have yellow highlighting, which prints as grey background when printed in Black and White.

We are conducting the group review via hard-copy print outs and not on computers because some members of the review group do not use google docs (I'm not sure if they even have computers) and/or have expressed desire to review hard copies so they can write on them.

Answer (score 0):

Google Docs does not support this feature natively, but here is a userstyle that will do what you want. Load it with an extension like Stylus ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/)). If you want a color other than yellow, replace `#FFAA00` with the color of your choice.

```
/* Changes highlighted text. /*
html body .suggestion-text-green {
    color: #FFAA00 !important;
    border-color: #FFAA00 !important;
}

/* Changes highlighted deletions (strikethrough). */
html body div[style*="border-top:3px solid #1FA15D"] {
    border-top: 3px solid #FFAA00 !important;
}

/* Changes the box that appears when you edit a suggestion. */
[class^="suggest-changes"][style*="rgb(31, 161, 93)"],
[class^="suggest-changes"][style*="#1FA15D"]{
    border-top-color: #FFAA00 !important;
    border-bottom-color: #FFAA00 !important;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Download the Google Doc as a Word doc and print that.  It will have all of the markup and comments just like they are in Word.   Very nice.

Comment: Is the file to be printed from Word? (Not everyone has that). Also, does this solve the problem of highlighting suggestions?